# Vertically Aligned Text in a Span

Tags: html, css

Here is My **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H4yuE/)**

```
<span class="boxPrice  ">
    <p>Previous Bill</p>

</span>
```

I want to create `<p>` inside a `<span>`

should be vertically aligned center inside the `<span>`

Comment: Block elements are not valid in span, afaik.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add

```
display:inline-block;
```

to your p element.

Answer (score 2):

Add `line-height:75px;` You need to make sure the line height is the same as the div height/

http://jsfiddle.net/H4yuE/1/

Comment: Brother id i add one more <p>Some text</p> it collapse  check this   http://jsfiddle.net/H4yuE/2/

Answer (score 1):

Block elements aren't "affected" by the `vertical-align: middle`, only inline elements...

I suggest changing the `p` to inline and adding the `vertical-align: middle`, like this:

```
.boxPrice p {
    padding:0 !important;
    margin:0 !important;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H4yuE/3/)**

Comment: Why would you use !important statements?

Answer (score 1):

1. I would rather not use a block level element ("p") element within an inline level element ("span"). Use div instead.
2. There are several tricks on how to do this, the simplest is to modify line-height to match the height of your container:

> ```
> .container {
>      width: 100px;
>      height: 100px;
>      line-height: 100px; /* Set it to the container height */
> }
> ```

You can also use "display: table-cell" to achieve the same effect:

```
 .container {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Comment: div i can also work, but i just want to use span and p, any way thans for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
.boxPrice
  {
 width:160px; height:75px; border:1px #333 solid; text-align:center; display:inline-block;}           
.boxPrice p{padding:20px !important; margin:0 !important}
.boxPrice:after{ display:inline-block; content:'';vertical-align:middle;  height:100%}
```